# How to get values multiple components of select values in php by using javascript

Tags: javascript, php

**For Example :**

**Batch :** 2014-2015      // this one of the select box(drop box)

**Department :**  Computer Science // this is also one the select box

finally

**Semester:**  Semester-1   // this is also one the select box

after clicking the semester select box i want to query the datas from database corresponding subjects of computer science and in particular department and batch

**subjects** : C++  // this is also one the select box

how to **get selected batch and department values when i am selecting the semester** select box (drop box) by using the javascript

can u show any example please

i tried the following code but not successful

```
echo "<select name='bat'>";
echo "<select name='dept'>";
echo "<select name='sem'  onchange='showUser(this.value)'>";
```

**JavaScript**

```
function showUser(str)
{

var bat = document.getElementsByName("bat").value;
var dept = document.getElementsByName("dept").value;


if (str=="") 
{
    document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML="";
    return;
} 

if (window.XMLHttpRequest) 
{
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  } 
else 
{ 
    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }

  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() 
{
    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) 
{
      alert(document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText);
    }
  }

xmlhttp.open("GET","../getsubject.php?q="+str + "&dept="+ dept +"&bat="+bat,true);
  xmlhttp.send();

}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

3 very simple pages

index.php

```
<form action="" method="POST">
Batch  <select name="Batch" id="Batch">
<option>2012-2013</option>
<option>2013-2014</option>
<option>2014-2015</option>
</select>                               <br>
<select name="department" id="department"></select>
</form>
<script src="jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="test.js"></script>
```

test.js

```
$("#Batch").change(function(){
    Batch=$("#Batch").val();
    $.ajax({
        datatype:"html",
        type: "POST",
        url: "ajax.php",
        data: {Batch:Batch},
        success: function(html)
        {
            $("#department").empty();
            $("#department").append(html);
        }
    }); 
});
```

ajax.php

```
<?php
if($_POST['Batch']=="2012-2013")
  echo "<option>first</option>";
if($_POST['Batch']=="2013-2014")
  echo "<option>second</option>";
if($_POST['Batch']=="2014-2015")
  echo "<option>THIRD</option>";
?>
```

Comment: what is the meaning of html(html1);

Comment: actually i new this ajax i used like by using <script> tag in drupal

Comment: .html(html1)
will mean that replace the code in `selector`  by this one `html1`

Comment: yes sir i am new to drupal and ajax. this code i am going to use in phpcode filter in drupal

Comment: thank robert, how to send two select box values to ajax.php. the above example only batch value sending to ajax.php. but i want to send two values to ajax.php for example batch value and department value based on that i want to display subjects values. please guide me how to do..